# adb not seeing device on Linux

Tags: android, linux, adb

I am running an hp laptop dual booted with windows8.1  and Linux mint17.2

When using Linux my adb will not communicate with the phone,when on windows I do not have any problem. I have redone the udev rules(as i now have 2 phone icons that pop up when the phone is plugged). I can see the options to transfer files,(drag n drop to sd card)and have done so.  but when I try to use adb for anything(I get no device found) or run "adb devices", all it says is "list of attached devices" when on Linux. but when I run the command on windows it lists the device .

I also have run the command of: lsusb, and gotten the results. the phone is listed. I prefer to work on my phone on Linux, so could someone PLEASE, help me figure this out. if i have left out ANY other important info just ask.

I am kind of new to both Linux and android so not really sure what one would need to know.

Sorry for any inconvenience. and thank you for any help.

Comment: You should edit your post to proper English: capitalize your I's, start sentences with capitals, etc.

Comment: you would like to see this and try to install : https://code.google.com/p/adb-fastboot-install/

Comment: answer found: [https://androidonlinux.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/setting-up-adb-on-linux/](https://androidonlinux.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/setting-up-adb-on-linux/)
it was this easy.

Answer (score 0):

For some devices you need an extra setup step as well as the udev rules. Try Googling "[your phone make and model] adb linux".